# ReferenceError: document is not defined (bootstrap.js) event hander

Tags: node.js, express, bootstrap-4

[EventHandler.on(document, clickEvent, `[data-bs-dismiss="${name}"]`, function (event) {](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLysF.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.